# Convert datetime string in datetime format in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm using MS SQL server and I have a date field of type text. The dates stored there are in this format

> 2017-03-01T18:23:02+0700

I'm trying to convert this field in a datetime field but I fail. I have tried

```
CONVERT(datetimeoffset,date, 127)
CONVERT(datetime,date, 127) 
CONVERT(datetime2,date, 127)
```

but I keep getting

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

I think the problem is that according to ISO8601 the time offset must be in the format hh:mm while mine is hhmm. I don't mind keeping only the date (yyyy-mm-dd) if it is more easy.

I have read similar question but none matches exactly my case and I can't figure out the solution.

Comment: if you only need date then use this select left('2017-03-01T18:23:02+0700',10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Declare @dt varchar(50)
set @dt = '2017-03-01T18:23:02+0700'
select convert(datetime, replace(LEFT(@dt, LEN(@dt) - 1), '+', '.'), 126)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need only date part then you can use below query

```
SELECT CAST(LEFT('2017-03-01T18:23:02+0700',10) as DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below query to convert datetime :

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,REPLACE(REPLACE('2017-03-01T18:23:02+070','T',' 
'),'+','.'),103)
```

For DATE only use below query :

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,REPLACE(REPLACE('2017-03-01T18:23:02+010','T',' 
 '),'+','.'),102)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to work in both ways (both raise error):

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'2017-03-01T18:23:02+0700',127)
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'2017-03-01T18:23:02+07:00',127)
```

It seems that it works only specifying Z as time zone:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,'2017-03-01T18:23:02Z',127)
```